# Does ELL support the math markup?

Tags: feature-request

Does the English Language Learners Stack Exchange support the TeX-like markup used by the Mathematics Stack Exchange to format complicated mathematical expressions?  This would make it easier to answer (rare) questions about [how to read mathematical expressions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42963).

[For example:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389435)

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x^p}{\int_0^{x}\ln(1 + \sin(t) + t)dt} {dx} $$

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ChatJax bookmarker we use in the math chatroom [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) to render it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your question in your question--need for this support is rare, and so likely to be deemed unnecessary. I'm also not entirely sure I think that question is on-topic: at the very least it's multiple questions in one. I know this is short answer, but my opinion on the matter is fairly succinct: this isn't a common enough problem to warrant a change.

Now, if you could collect a larger list of questions needing this support and build a case for why it would be an improvement for the site, that would be another story. If you can do that, and gain community support for the initiative (usually measured in net votes on the question), then the mod team can easily bring this to the attention of SE staff and get a ruling. But at this time I just don't see it as necessary.